# how to find breakpoint in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a project containing hundreds of files.

I put debugger points, which are now no more reach.

I wanna find all of them to make sure if the problem there was where the point was is still there.

I know I can remove all the points easily. However, is there a way to do a `goto` debugger points?.

I'm using visual studio 2013

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question about a programming tool. Not sure why it attracted a downvote.

Comment: Someone is actually trying to use a debugger when posting.  When's the last time we saw that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, or select **Debug** > **Windows** > **Breakpoints** to open the Breakpoints window.

There, you will find a list of all breakpoints, including the filename and line number. You can double-click a breakpoint, or right-click and select "Go To Source Code".

Answer (score 2):

open the breakpoints window and double click on a bp, it will navigate to the bp source location

debug>windows>breakpoints